# Show value not existing in another table SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, cursor

I want to show the value in EXTRA_CALL that not exist in TBL_CALLPLAN.
I have query is:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select a.CODE, a.NAME from EXTRA_CALL a LEFT JOIN TBL_CALLPLAN b ON b.CCODE=a.CODE " +
                "WHERE b.CCODE IS NULL", null);
```

when i run that query, the value always show all in EXTRA_CALL table. Where is my fault?

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with this query, assuming it is what you want to do.  Your query would return records in `EXTRA_CALL` which did _not_ match to anything in `TBL_CALLPLAN`.  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: i want to show the value in EXTRA_CALL that not exist in TBL_CALLPLAN

Comment: ThEn it means that all the extra calls you can see do not exist in call plan. Are you sure you joined the tables using the correct column?

Comment: Agree with @CaiusJard maybe nothing is matching, hence you get the entire table back.

Comment: Post the results of SELeCT * FROM (each your tables) so we can see your data

Comment: the column in tbl_callplan is ccode and the column in extra_call is code. i'm sure for this

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query make my problem solve:

```
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select a.CODE, a.NAME from EXTRA_CALL a where " +
            "not a.code in (select ccode from tbl_callplan) order by a.custname asc", null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Either there really is no matching EXTRACALL row for every CALLPLAN row, or your SQLite suffers from the same bug some versions of Oracle 9i did where the order of the tables in the ON condition mattered. Swap it round so the query says `on a.code=b.ccode` and see if the result is different. It shouldn't be, but when working with that ancient version of oracle, it certainly expected the table on the left side of the JOIN keyword to also be the one stated on the left side of the = if doing a left join. Maybe SQLite has this bad habit too